# Esxi not reading all installed memory

Tags: vmware, esxi, virtual-memory

So i have esxi with installed memory 12 GB
The vmware reads 8gb only

I have raid hardesk
And SSD THICK PROVISIONS data store
So why the esxi reads only 8GB?

Comment: Why do you think you have 12 GB? The most likely explanation is that the RAM is not properly installed.

Comment: Because the bios of the esxi says 12gb install ed

Comment: Please add to your post the exact model of your computer and the RAM sticks and in which DIMMs you have installed them.

Comment: Dim 1 to dim 6. Memory ram 2 gigs each
Dell t7500

Comment: The bios reads the 12gb but vmware reads 8gb

Comment: How many vCPUs for the VM? Try to manually edit the `.vmx` to set `memsize = "12288"`. If when starting the VM you get warning dialog box, set it to "Never show this dialog box again".

Comment: 4cores.. how can i edit . Vmx.. why the 4gigd difference not readable